# Is there any mathematical way to describe this Input/Output Machine?

Tags: functions

How would you make a function for this Input/Output:

For example, 3:

- You multiply x (3) by itself
- Then you multiply x - 1 (2) by itself and add it to 9 (3 squared)
  And so on.....

You could say it's x squared + x - 1 squared and so on, but I'm looking for a way to write this as an arithmetic equation.

EDIT: The formula for this is 1/6x (x + 1) x (2x + 1). Thank you to yurnero and sranthrop.

Comment: You don't have to add answers you like to your question. You can just "Accept" one of them by giving it the tickmark, located to the left, below the arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: From the comments, I take that your function is
$$
x\mapsto\sum_{j=0}^{x-1}(x-j)^2=x^2+(x-1)^2+\cdots+1.
$$
An explicit formula for the RHS above exists:
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{j=0}^{x-1}(x-j)^2&=1^2+2^2+\cdots+x^2\\
&=\frac{1}{6}x(1+x)(1+2x).
\end{aligned}
You can prove $1^2+2^2+\cdots+x^2=\frac{1}{6}x(1+x)(1+2x)$ by induction on $x$. For an answer on MSE, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/629135/178464).

Comment: What I meant was like this table: 1 = 1, 2 = 3, 3 = 16, 4 = 30

Comment: @TigerGold How is $2\mapsto 3$?

Comment: 2 * 2 + 1 * 1 + 0 * 0

Comment: @TigerGold Which equals $5$.

Comment: lol oh how did I fail

Comment: Just a stupid mess up

Comment: And then 16 should be 14

Comment: But other than that I'm correct

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound stupid

Comment: Please forgive me

Comment: Thank you, I probably sounded ridiculous

Answer (score 1):

If your sequence is $1\mapsto 1^2, 2\mapsto 1^2+2^2, 3\mapsto1^2+2^2+3^3,...$, then this can be shortly written as
\begin{align*}
n\mapsto \sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{1}{6} n (1 + n) (1 + 2 n).
\end{align*}
For example, if you want to know what 5 is mapped to, just plug in $n=5$ and obtain $\frac{1}{6}\cdot 5\cdot(1+5)\cdot(1+2\cdot 5)=55.$

Comment: Thank you, as well as yurnero