# Combination of quadratic and arithmetic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, arithmetic, exponentiation

**Problem:**

> Calculate $\dfrac{1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+\cdots+23333330^2}{1+2+3+4+\cdots+23333330}$.

---

**Attempt:**

I know the denominator is arithmetic series and equals
$$\frac{n}{2}(T_1+T_n)=\frac{23333330}{2}(1+23333330)=272222156111115,$$
but how do I calculate the numerator without using a calculator?

Comment: Do you know how to find the sum of squares?

Comment: I dunno. Can you help me Calvin?

Comment: Lab stated the formulas in his solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Intuitively,
\begin{align}
S_1&=\frac{1^2}{1}=1=\frac{3}{3}\\
S_2&=\frac{1^2+2^2}{1+2}=\frac{5}{3}\\
S_3&=\frac{1^2+2^2+3^2}{1+2+3}=\frac{7}{3}\\
S_4&=\frac{1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2}{1+2+3+4}=3=\frac{9}{3}\\
\vdots\\
\large\color{blue}{S_n}&\color{blue}{=\frac{2n+1}{3}}.
\end{align}

Comment: This solution appears to be more elegant than others!

Comment: This is smart way. Genius! (y)(y)

Answer (score 6):

$$S_1=\sum_{r=1}^nr =\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

and $$S_2=\sum_{r=1}^nr^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$

So, the ratio  $\dfrac{S_2}{S_1}$ should not demand calculator

Comment: What do you think the OP learned from seeing this? One more formula to be memorized?

Comment: @doank, See : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183316/how-to-get-to-the-formula-for-the-sum-of-squares-of-first-n-numbers

Comment: How to get the formula sum of squares?

Comment: @doank: when search $S_2(n)$ as polynomial $S_2(n)=an^3+bn^2+cn$ (due to intuition :), then $$S_2(n)-S_2(n-1) = n^2$$ can help here.

Comment: @Oleg567 I don't get it yet. Sorry :(

Comment: @doank,$$S_2(n)= 1^2+2^2+\ldots+(n-1)^2+n^2,$$
$$S_2(n-1)= 1^2+2^2+\ldots+(n-1)^2,$$
so $$S_2(n) = S_2(n-1)+n^2,\tag{1}$$
or $$S_2(n)-S_2(n-1) = n^2,\tag{2}$$
Now, if you'll search $S(n)$ as $$S(n)=an^3+bn^2+cn,$$ ($S(0)=0$, so last term "$+d$" is void), then $(2) \Rightarrow$

$$
an^3+bn^2+cn - a(n-1)^3 - b(n-1)^2-c(n-1)=n^2;
$$
$$
an^3+bn^2+cn - a(n^3-3n^2+3n-1) -b(n^2-2n+1)-c(n-1)=n^2;
$$
$$
3a n^2 +(-3a+2b)n + (a-b+c)=n^2;
$$
so
$$
3a=1;\\
-3a+2b=0;\\
a-b+c=0;
$$
and hence we can find $a=\dfrac{1}{3}$, $b=\dfrac{1}{2}$, $c=\dfrac{1}{6}$.

Comment: @Oleg567 Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it :)