# Combination of quadratic and cubic series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, exponentiation

I'm an eight-grader and I need help to answer this math problem (homework).

**Problem:**

> Calculate $$\frac{1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+...+1000^2}{1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3+...+1000^3}$$

**Attempt:**

I know how to calculate the quadratic sum using formula from here: [Combination of quadratic and arithmetic series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865398/combination-of-quadratic-and-arithmetic-series) but how to calculate the cubic sum? How to calculate the series without using calculator? Is there any intuitive way like previous answer? Please help me. Grazie!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have identities for sums of powers like these. In particular:

$$1^2 + 2^2 + \dots + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

$$1^3 + 2^3 + \dots + n^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$

The rest is just a bit of arithmetic.

Comment: Similar to theage, you might find it helpful to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula, which contains a few more common cases in the examples section.

Comment: The general cases may be a bit scary for an eighth-grader, however.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how do I know the formula for cubic sum is $\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$?

Comment: When coming up with power sums like these, it's often very difficult to come up with an elementary intuition. If you've seen proofs by induction, that's the standard way of verifying the identity.

Comment: Not really a hint :)

Answer (score -1):

It is a quadraic sequence as 1,4,9,16,25,36 ........//

Its first term (a)=1
1st difference (d)=4-1=3
2nd difference i.e. constant difference(c)=2

There is a sum formula for any quadraic equation which is

Sn=n/6[(n-1)3d+(n-1)(n-2)C]+an
This is for any quadraic even for sum of squares.

I have sum formula for cubic sequence.Let "b" be 1st
difference "c" be 2nd difference and "d" be 3rd diffrrence
.Also "a" is first term."n" is no. of term.Put all value in
below formula except "n" to get sum formula of any cubic
sequence.

sum formula

Sn=n/24*[(n-1)12b+(n-1)(n-2)4c+(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)d]+an

Both formula are 100% working.

Comment: It is a quadraic sequence as 1,4,9,16,25,36 ........//

Its first term (a)=1
1st difference (d)=4-1=3
2nd difference i.e. constant difference(c)=2

There is a sum formula for any quadraic equation which is 

Sn=n/6*[(n-1)3d+(n-1)(n-2)c]+an

Putting above value in this formula,we get

Sn=n/6*[(n-1)3*3+(n^2-3n+2)2]+1n

     =n/6[9n-9+2n^2-6n+4]+n

      =n/6[2n^2+3n-5]+n

      =n/6[2n^2+3n-5+6]

       =n/6[2n^2+3n+1]

       =n/6(2n+1)(n+1)


Which is final answer.There is also sum formula for cubic and even quartic sequence.