# Summation of series involving logarithm: $\sum (n+2)\ln 2^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

The following question is:

> Show that $\sum\limits_{r = 1}^n {r(r + 2)}  ={n \over 6}(n+1)(2n+7).$
>
> Using this results, or otherwise, find, in terms of $n$, the sum of the series $$3\ln2+4\ln2^2+5\ln2^3+\dots +(n+2)\ln(2^n)$$ Express your answer in its simplest form.

ps: I have shown the result but having problem with the second part which is to find the sum of the series. I had no idea where to start.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Since $\log(2^n)=n\log(2)$, then $$\sum_{i=1}^n (i+2)\log(2^i)=\sum_{i=1}^n i(i+2)\log(2)=\log(2) \sum_{i=1}^n i(i+2)$$

I am sure that you can take from here

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{r=1}^nr(r+2)=\sum_{r=1}^nr^2+2\sum_{r=1}^nr$$

See [sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) of first $n$ natural number $\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$

and [How to get to the formula for the sum of squares of first n numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183316/how-to-get-to-the-formula-for-the-sum-of-squares-of-first-n-numbers)

Now, $$\ln2^r=r\ln2\implies (r+2)(\ln2^r)=r(r+2)\ln2$$

$$\implies\sum_{r=1}^n(r+2)(\ln2^r)=\ln2\sum_{r=1}^nr(r+2)=?$$

Comment: You won AGAIN ! Cheers :)