# How to simplify $1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+n^2=？$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

How to simplify 
$1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+n^2= \text{?}$
help……………………
thank you

Comment: What do you mean by simplifying?

Comment: Was this presented in a certain context? Are you just wondering? Any work you've tried will help. This is a well know identity, do you have any thoughts on this? Empirical observations? Guesses?

Comment: Also, calculus is an inappropriate tag here.

Comment: @DhruvSomani Factorization…………

Comment: There is a well-known formula, as stated in the answers below. Simple derivation can be found in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number

Comment: You would have to prove the given answers by induction or perhaps the Well Ordering Principle.

Comment: Maybe this can help:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183316/how-to-get-to-the-formula-for-the-sum-of-squares-of-first-n-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can evaluate the sum a number of ways.  Here, we present two approaches, both of which rely on the sum of the arithmetic progression $\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac12n(n+1)$.

METHODOLOGY $1$:

Here, we note that $\sum_{j=1}^k(1)=k$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^nk^2&=\sum_{k=1}^nk\sum_{j=1}^k(1)\\\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=j}^n\,k\\\\
&=\frac12\sum_{j=1}^n(n+1-j)(j+n)\\\\
&=\frac12\sum_{j=1}^n\left(n(n+1)+j-j^2\right)\\\\
&=\frac12n^2(n+1)+\frac14n(n+1)-\frac12\sum_{j=1}^nj^2\\\\
\frac32\sum_{k=1}^nk^2&=\frac{(2n+1)n(n+1)}{4}\\\\
\sum_{k=1}^nk^2&=\frac{(2n+1)n(n+1)}{6}
\end{align}$$

---

METHODOLOGY $2$:  Making use of a telescoping sum

Note that we have $\sum_{k=1}^n\left((k+1)^3-k^3\right)=(n+1)^3-1$ since the summands are telescoping.  Then, by expanding the term $(n+1)^3$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
(n+1)^3-1&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left((k+1)^3-k^3\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(3k^2+3k+1\right)\\\\
&=3\sum_{k=1}^nk^2+3\sum_{k=1}^nk+\sum_{k=1}^n(1)\\\\
&=3\sum_{k=1}^nk^2+\frac{3n(n+1)}{2}+n\\\\
\frac{(n+1)^3-1-\frac{3n(n+1)}{2}-n}{3}&=\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\\\\
\frac{(2n+1)n(n+1)}{6}&=\sum_{k=1}^nk^2
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Two "methodologies 1"?..

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks for the catch.  I've edited accordingly.  - Mark

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum n^2= \frac{(n)(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$ thats the simplification nothing much in it.

Comment: but how to get this

Comment: Do you know mathematical induction

Answer (score 1):

It's equals to
$$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$ 
It can be proven by using induction mehod.