# Question about motion.

Tags: brownian-motion

I don't know how to solve this problem . Please anyone help.
Question:-

An object start moving from immobility with a acceleration of " **f m/s^2**". At the end of every t seconds it increases it acceleration by "**f m/s^2**".
Show that after "**nt** seconds" the velocity is "**n(n+1)ft/2**" and the object has moved **(n(n+1)(2n+1)ft^2)/2** meters.

Comment: Recall that for constant accelerated motion $v(t)=v(0)+t a$ and $x(t)=x(0)+tv(0)+\frac{1}{2}at^2$. Now add the contributions of the various time intervals $[0,t]\cup[t,2t]\cup\cdots\cup[(n-1)t,nt]$.

Comment: @b00nheT please show me how to get the final answer

Comment: No. You do it: start by considering the first time interval. $[0,t]$ What is the velocity at time $t$? How far have you travelled? Then start again the problem at $t$ and go till $2t$ and argue as you did before. Do this $n$ times and you'll get the answer. I will help you further only if you show me you have tried.

Comment: @b00nheT yes I tried.I got answers for various time intervals. For t s = 0.5m , 2t s = 2m, 3t s = 4.5m, 4t s = 8 m but i dont know how to show what asked in the question.Please help me to show that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Starting at $t=0$ the object has velocity $v(0)=0$ and acceleration $f\ \frac{m}{s^2}$.
Thus at time $t$, by the above mentioned formulas, the object will have travelled
$$x(t)=\frac12t^2f\ \text{ meters}, $$
and will have a velocity of 
$$v(t)=ft \  \frac{m}{s}.$$
Between time $t$ and $2t$ it will have travelled, accounting for $\color{red}{\text{the increment in acceleration}}$
$$x(2t)-x(t)=v(t)\cdot t+ \frac12t^2(f\color{red}{+f})\ \text { meters}$$
and will have a final velocity of 
$$v(2t)=v(t)+t(f+f)\ \frac{m}{s}.$$
It is now quite clear, this you can prove by inspection, that between time $kt$ and time $(k+1)t$ your object will travel
$$x((k+1)t)-x(kt)=v(kt)\cdot t+ \frac12t^2((k+1)f)\ \text { meters}$$
and its final velocity will be
$$v((k+1)t)-v(kt)=t((k+1)f)\ \frac{m}{s}.$$
Now we sum all contributions, to see that
$$v(Kt)=\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\left[v((k+1)t)-v(kt)\right]+v(0)=\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\left[t((k+1)f)\right]+0=tf \sum_{k=0}^{K-1}(k+1)=tf\frac{K(K+1)}{2},$$
so that in particular,
$$v(nt)=tf\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$
Similarly
\begin{align*}x(nt)& =\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[x((k+1)t)-x(kt)\right]+x(0)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[v(kt)\cdot t+ \frac12t^2((k+1)f)\right]+x(0)\\ & =t^2f\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k(k+1)}{2}+ \frac12t^2 f\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+1)\\& = t^2f\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[\frac{k(k+1)}{2}+\frac{k+1}{2}\right] \\ & = \frac{t^2f}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1)^2 \\ & = \frac{t^2f}{2}\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
\end{align*}

Where in the last step I have used the sum of squares formula ([How to get to the formula for the sum of squares of first n numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183316/how-to-get-to-the-formula-for-the-sum-of-squares-of-first-n-numbers)).

Remark: I suppose the suggested answer is missing a $1/6$ factor