# Sum of the first $n$ quadratic integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, quadratics, cubics

I'm from Italy so maybe my English could be bad. To prove that
$$
S=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 = \frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}
$$
we can consider the series:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left((k-1)^3-k^3\right) \, .
$$
Note that
\begin{align}
(k-1)^3 &= k^3 -1 -3k^2 +3k \\[5pt]
(k-1)^3 - k^3 &= -1 -3k^2 +3k
\end{align}
and so
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}((k-1)^3 - k^3) &= \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1 -3k^2 +3k) \\[5pt]
-n^3 &= -n -3S + \frac{3n(n+1)}{2}
\end{align}
etc etc

I understand why this proof works, but I dont understand the initial thought to use $(k-1)^3$ and same for $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^3$ we can start from $(k-1)^4$ and so on. Which reason there is behind that?

I hope to have been clear. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: You want to know why the sum of **$k^2$**, but you use expressions cubed????

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2= 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 ....$

Comment: @amWhy: In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183316/how-to-get-to-the-formula-for-the-sum-of-squares-of-first-n-numbers/183320#183320) thread, it is explained how you can use $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left((k+1)^3-k^3\right)$ to find the sum of $n$ square numbers.

Comment: Then please include that link in the question post on behalf of Edward, @Joe.

Comment: @amWhy: It's done. Now I look at things more closely, Edward considers the series $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left((k-1)^3-k^3\right)$ but the idea is obviously the same.

Comment: Incidentally, the usual term for the values $k^2$ for natural numbers $k$ is "squares" (or "perfect squares").  So the title of your post would more typically be written as "Sum of the first $n$ (positive) squares."

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, good things happen when you can evaluate something in two different ways. The telescoping series
$$
S_1=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(k-1)^3-k^3 \, ,
$$
can be evaluated using the ['method of differences'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), where most of the terms are cancelled out. This tells us that
$$
S_1=-n^3 \, .
$$
However, we *also* know that
$$
S_1=\sum_{k=0}^{n}-3k^2+3k-1 \tag{*}\label{*} \, .
$$
which expresses $S_1$ in terms of the unknown $S=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$. Because we already know that $S_1=-n^3$ using the method of differences, we can rearrange $\eqref{*}$  to make $S$ the subject of the equation and solve.

The same principle applies when computing series such as $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3$: because we can evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k-1)^4-k^4$ in two different ways, this gives us enough information to find $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3$.

Comment: Look, u just repeat what I know yet. Imagine a world where the telescoping series formula wasnt discovered yet; imagine you are the one that should proof the formula I asked; how can u think to adjust your  $k^a$  equation by start from $(k-1)^{a+1}$?

Comment: @Edward: It makes a lot of sense to find a sum that you already know the value of which can be expressed in terms of the unknown $\sum k^a$. One way to find a sum that you already of is to consider other summation methods, such as the 'method of differences'. I'm sorry if this isn't the kind of answer that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general answer than what you are actually asking.

The reason is for me as follows: you only know the sums for $\ell< \ell_0$, and you want to calculate $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{\ell_0} $$

The terms in $(k+1)^{\ell_0+1}-k^{\ell_0+1}$ are all of the form $\alpha_{\ell} k^{\ell}$ with $\ell \leq \ell_0$ so you know how to calculate each $$\alpha_{\ell}\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n  k^{\ell} \quad \forall \ell<\ell_0$$

Except $$\alpha_{\ell_0}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{\ell_0} $$

Moreover, $\sum_{k=1}^n \left((k+1)^{\ell_0+1}-k^{\ell_0+1}\right) $ is a telescoping sum so it is really easy to calculate.

You can see that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left((k+1)^{\ell_0+1}-k^{\ell_0+1}\right) = (n+1)^{\ell_0+1}-1 $$

Therefore it gives you enough information to determine,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{\ell_0}  $$