# how can one find the value of the expression, $(1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+n^2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16)
>   [Summation of natural number set with power of $m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65861/summation-of-natural-number-set-with-power-of-m)
>   [How to get to the formula for the sum of squares of first n numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183316/how-to-get-to-the-formula-for-the-sum-of-squares-of-first-n-numbers)

how can one find the value of the expression, $(1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+n^2)$

Let,

$T_{2}(n)=1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+n^2$

$T_{2}(n)=(1^2+n^2)+(2^2+(n-1)^2)+\cdots$

$T_{2}(n)=((n+1)^2-2(1)(n))+((n+1)^2-2(2)(n-1))+\cdots$

Comment: @RossMillikan but that duplicate doesn't really provide much help for the OP.

Comment: I'm trying to locate another question that deals specifically with $1^2 + 2^2 \dots + n^2$. Search sucks!

Comment: @JenniferDylan:  Robert Israel's answer provides a nice link for powers besides 2

Comment: @RossMillikan may be you're right. I was quick in my judgement. I just want us to slow down on the closures a bit.

Comment: @JenniferDylan: I am pretty sure this has been asked before, I just can't find it.  Also, thanks for providing the link on that other question, I added them to the list of generalizations of common questions because they are asked so often.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95047/combinatorial-interpretation-of-sum-of-squares-cubes  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122546/gaussian-proof-for-the-sum-of-squares and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65861/summation-of-natural-number-set-with-power-of-m

Comment: Also [How do I come up with a function to count a pyramid of apples?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24521/how-do-i-come-up-with-a-function-to-count-a-pyramid-of-apples)  
[Proof that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16)  
[Finite Sum of Power?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155166/finite-sum-of-power)

Comment: I downvoted because I thought Rajesh should have caught a clue after his sum-of-cubes question was closed an hour before.

Comment: @Jennifer I am sympathetic to the argument that we too often close questions as "duplicates" when they are not, and that closers should take more care to make sure that the similar questions are really close.  But in this case I think there are not only one but several *exact* duplicates.

Comment: @JenniferDylan, your memory is good, it was asked before on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $(n+1)^3-n^3=3n^2+3n+1$ and use telescopic sum.

Answer (score 3):

In general, $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{2} = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

A collection of proofs of this fact can be found [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Sequence_of_Squares).

Answer (score 2):

The claim is that

$\sum_{i = 1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}$

We will verify this by induction.

Clearly $n = 1$ holds.

Suppose the formula holds for $n$. Lets verify it holds for $n + 1$.

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n + 1} i^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^n i^2 + (n + 1)^2 = \frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6} + (n + 1)^2
\\
= \frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6} + \frac{6(n^2 + 2n + 1)}{6}
\\
= \frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 + n}{6} + \frac{6n^2 + 12 n + 6}{6}
\\
= \frac{2n^3 + 9n^2 + 13n + 6}{6}$$

If you factor you get

$$= \frac{(n + 1)(n + 2)(2n + 3)}{6} = \frac{(n + 1)((n + 1) + 1)(2(n + 1) + 1)}{6}$$

The result follows for $n + 1$. So by induction the formula holds.

Comment: LaTeX tip: MathJax supports `$$ $$` for center-line display math. Also inside `$$ $$` MathJax supports `\\` for new lines.

Comment: @JenniferDylan Thanks. It works a lot more like LaTex than I thought.

Comment: [$\TeX$ / $\LaTeX$ / MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

If you can find or sketch some 3D blocks, there is a fun geometric proof.

Fix some $n$. If you are doing this with real blocks, $n=3$ or $4$ should be convincing. Let's take $n=4$ for now.

Make a $4\times 4\times 1$ base, laid flat, which of course has volume $4^2$.

Now make a $3\times 3 \times 1$ brick and place it, laid flat, above the base with some corners aligned. Continue in this way up to the top, making smaller squares and always aligning with the same corner. You now have a 3D corner of stairs whose volume is $1^2+\cdots +n^2$.

Now the fun part. Make 5 more of these "stair corners", for a total of 6. These six toys can be turned sideways and upside down, and then pieced together to make an $n\times(n+1)\times(2n+1)$ rectangular solid.