# Easy proof for sum of squares $\approx n^3/3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, alternative-proof

I'd like to prove to my (undergraduate, not math-major) students that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 =\frac{1}{3},
$$
to later show them that this can be interpreted as taking Riemann sums for the integral of $x^2$. Of course I could pull out of my hat the formula $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$, which makes it obvious, or start from the telescopic sum 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n ((k+1)^3-k^3)
$$
and do some algebra. Neither of them sounds very convincing to me, since they will be new ideas for them, not immediate to grasp, and this should not be the central point of my lecture.

**Is there a simpler way to work out this limit, without going through a proof for the value of the sum?**

Comment: A very rough heuristic would replace the $k^2$ by $\frac{n^2}{2}$ so that
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\approx\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n^2}{2}= n\cdot\frac{n^2}{2}=\frac{n^3}{2}.$$ 

That would be the why the $n^3$ makes an appearance.

Comment: If you're not working on this being particularly rigorous, you could interpret the sum as a square pyramid, and then quote the volume for such a shape.

Comment: Also, you could just put numbers in - the limit converges pretty quickly.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood I like your suggestions. If you formulate them as an answer, you'll have my upvote.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Done, glad to be of help.

Comment: The sum $1^2+2^2+\ldots+n^2$ has been discussed here many times.  If you look at [the answers here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188602/how-can-one-find-the-value-of-the-expression-122232-cdotsn2) or the ones linked in the "linked" sidebar on that page, you will probably find something suitable.

Comment: @MJD I don't think it's the same question. I would like to find a quick proof for that limit *without* going through a whole proof of the closed form for the sum.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I didn't say it was the same question; that's why I didn't vote to close your question as a duplicate.  I was only trying to helpfully point out that this has been discussed here many times, and that, after discarding the proofs using the Snorfus quasisymmetric tensor theorem or whatever, there is probably something you will find useful.  For example, the [currently top-voted answer in *this* thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/718277/25554) has already appeared [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/48152/25554).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to make this limit seem intuitive. [The sum of the squares can be interpreted as a square pyramid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_numbers); the volume of such a pyramid is *approximately* $\frac{1}3 n^{3}$.

Another method could be to just calculate some of the partial sums. For example,
$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{10}k^{2}}{10^{3}}=0.385 \approx 1/3$$

Comment: Other good answers in the thread, but this one seems the most practical approach to me, so I am accepting this one. I am all for creative proofs of that identity, but I'd like to have something that the bottom 50% of the class can understand.

Answer (score 17):

[image]

${                                                      }$

Comment: Nice. This also answers why formula of volumes of pyramids also include 1/3 in them instead of going through the integral. Easier to explain for secondary school!

Answer (score 4):

The limit is suitable for Stolz-Cesaro:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2\over n^3}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}{(n+1)^2\over (n+1)^3-n^3}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}{n^2+2n+1\over 3n^2+3n+1}={1\over 3}.
$$
In fact, repeating the trick with $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 -\frac{n^3}{3}$, you can calculate the coefficient of $n^2$ in $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$... until the full formula.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
2\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 & = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 + \sum_{k=1}^n(n-k+1)^2 \\
\\
& \approx \sum_{k=1}^n (n-k)^2 - (ik)^2
\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^n (n-(1+i)k)(n+(-i-1)k)
\\
& \approx \sum_{k=1}^n(n-ik)^2
\end{align*}

Taking the real part

\begin{align*}
2\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 & \approx \sum_{k=1}^nn^2 - \sum_{k=1}^nk^2
\end{align*}
and so
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 & \approx \frac{n^3}{3}
\end{align*}