# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1^4+2^4+\dots+n^4}{1^4+2^4+\dots+n^4+(n+1)^4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am just trying to calculate 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1^4+2^4+\dots+n^4}{1^4+2^4+\dots+n^4+(n+1)^4}.$$
To do this I apply formula for sum of fourth powers of $n$ number. My result: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1^4+2^4+\dots+n^4}{1^4+2^4+\dots+n^4+(n+1)^4}=1$$. I'm intrested in finding other method to solve the following problem.

Comment: [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)?

Comment: This gives a very short answer seee below: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718939/what-is-the-sum-of-14-24-34-dots-n4-and-the-derivation-for-that-ex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the sum of $1^4 + 2^4 + 3^4+ \dots + n^4$ and the derivation for that expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718939/what-is-the-sum-of-14-24-34-dots-n4-and-the-derivation-for-that-ex)

Comment: @amWhy: Not the same question. We don't need the closed-form for the sum of 4th-powers to find the limit here. A slick solution is to use integrals to bound each of the numerator and denominator, and then the limit falls out immediately. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\ell\in \mathbb R$ be a finite number. If
$$\lim _{n\to \infty }{\frac {a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{b_{n+1}-b_{n}}}=\ell ,\ $$
then, the limit
$${\displaystyle \lim _{n\to \infty }{\frac {a_{n}}{b_{n}}}=\ell .\ }$$
This is the Stolz–Cesàro theorem. In your case
$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^4, \quad b_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^4$$
and
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=(n+1)^4, \quad b_{n+1}-b_n=(n+2)^4,$$
so the limit is equal to 1.

Comment: (+1) When reading the question, this is the idea that came to mind, only I used $\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{b_n-b_{n-1}}$.

Answer (score 4):

As remarked by SBA, by denoting $1^4+2^4+\ldots+n^4$ as $p(n)$ we have
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{p(n)}{p(n+1)} \stackrel{\text{Stoltz-Cesàro}}{=}\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n^4}{(n+1)^4} = 1 $$
but the same conclusion simply follows from the observation that $p(n)$ *is a polynomial*.

Comment: @robjohn: I like to use Cesaro-Stolz as often as possible, but try to avoid L'Hospital's Rule as much as possible. I realized quite late that the fundamental difference between the two is that Cesaro-Stolz can be proved without using completeness but L'Hospital's Rule requires completeness so that Cesaro-Stolz is a simpler and effective tool.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\frac{1^4+2^4+\dots+n^4}{1^4+2^4+\dots+n^4+(n+1)^4}
=\frac{1^4+2^4+\dots+n^4+(n+1)^4-(n+1)^4}{1^4+2^4+\dots+n^4+(n+1)^4}
$$

Comment: You must add that the denominator will be a polynomial with degree 5!

Comment: I mean for finding that the limit is $1$, you need degree of denominator is greater than 4 for second term to be zero. Well I may be wrong.

Comment: To sum up: "hint" of what?

Answer (score 0):

If
$a_n > 0,
s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_n,
r_n = s_{n+1}/s_n$,
then,
if $a_{n+1}/a_n \to 1$,
$r_n \to 1$.

Proof:
$r_n-1
=a_{n+1}/s_n
$.
Since 
$a_{n+1}/a_n \to 1$,
then,
for any fixed $m$,
$a_{n+k}/a_n \to 1$
for $1 \le k \le m$.

Therefore,
for any fixed $m$,
$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{s_n}
\lt \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} a_{n-k}}
\to \dfrac1{m}
$
so that
$r_n-1
=\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{s_n}
\to 0
$.

Your case is
$a_n = n^4$,
and it is easy to show that
$a_{n+1}/a_n \to 0$.
This holds for
$a_n = n^p$
for any fixed $p$.

Answer (score 0):

### Very short Answer

From this [What is the sum of $1^4 + 2^4 + 3^4+ \dots + n^4$ and the derivation for that expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718939/what-is-the-sum-of-14-24-34-dots-n4-and-the-derivation-for-that-ex)
we have that,
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{4} = \frac{n^{5}}{5} + \frac{n^{4}}{2} + \frac{n^{3}}{3} - \frac{n}{30}.$$
Therefore, **By polynomial limit we have,** 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1^4+2^4+\dots+n^4}{1^4+2^4+\dots+n^4+(n+1)^4}= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n^{5}}{5} + \frac{n^{4}}{2} + \frac{n^{3}}{3} - \frac{n}{30}.}{\frac{n^{5}}{5} + \frac{n^{4}}{2} + \frac{n^{3}}{3} - \frac{n}{30}.+(n+1)^4}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

From this result: [why is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^m$ a polynomial with degree $m+1$ in $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18983/why-is-sum-limits-k-1n-km-a-polynomial-with-degree-m1-in-n)

Then $\dfrac{1^4+2^4+...+n^4+(n+1)^4}{1^4+2^4+...+n^4}=1+\dfrac{(n+1)^4}{O(n^5)}=1+O(\frac 1n)\to 1$ and so is the inverse of that.