# How to calculate the sum of $(n-1)^2+(n-2)^2+...+1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How to calculate the sum of the following series? $$(n-1)^2+(n-2)^2+...+1$$Thank you in advance

Comment: I'll google it for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number

Comment: What have you tried?  There are a few ways to find this sum, so if you describe your approach, where you are stuck, and any similar problems you have worked on then it will be more likely that you get an answer that is especially tailored to your needs.  As it is, this question does not give any context and does not meet the quality standards here on Math.SE.

Comment: Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sx0hM2IpIY&noredirect=1) explaining the solution.

Comment: This is a finite sum, rather than a series (even if it every finite sum is a series...). And what you are looking for is a [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula).

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320985/how-to-determine-equation-for-sum-k-1n-k3/321000#321000). Note that, $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(n-k)^2 \implies n^2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}1-2n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 1 $.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I come up with a function to count a pyramid of apples?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24521/how-do-i-come-up-with-a-function-to-count-a-pyramid-of-apples), also [(2)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16), [(3)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155166/finite-sum-of-power), [(4)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183316/how-to-get-to-the-formula-for-the-sum-of-squares-of-first-n-numbers).

Comment: Also [(5)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188602/how-can-one-find-the-value-of-the-expression-122232-cdotsn2), [(6)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65861/summation-of-natural-number-set-with-power-of-m).

Comment: @vadim123 Thank you very much

Comment: @Harold  Thank you very much

Comment: @MJD Thank you very much

Comment: @julien: Thanks for the comment. $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(n-k)^2 \implies n^2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}1-2n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^2$.

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal Thank you very much

Comment: @proofy: You are welcome.

Comment: I do not really understand why this was closed as too localized. This particular summation is certainly of interesting (although well known). That said I can see that this is an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2 &= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\\
\implies \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^2&= \hspace{1mm}?
\end{align*}

Comment: This ISN'T an answer.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @pedrosuavo Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

First recall the following:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 1 = n-1$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k = \dfrac{n(n-1)}2$$
Now we have the identity
$$(k+1)^3 - k^3 = 3k^2 + 3k + 1$$
Write this for $k=1,2,\ldots, n-2$ and we get
\begin{align}
2^3-1^3 & = 3 \cdot 1^2 + 3 \cdot 1 + 1\\
3^3-2^3 & = 3 \cdot 2^2 + 3 \cdot 2 + 1\\
4^3-3^3 & = 3 \cdot 3^2 + 3 \cdot 3 + 1\\
\vdots & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \vdots\\
n^3-(n-1)^3 & = 3 \cdot (n-1)^2 + 3 \cdot (n-1) + 1\\
\end{align}
Add these up and note that there is a telescopic cancellation on the left hand side to give
$$n^3 - 1^3 = 3 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^2 + 3 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 1$$
Hence, we get that
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^2 & = \dfrac{n^3 - 1}3 -\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k - \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 1}3 = \dfrac{n^3 -1}3 - \dfrac{n(n-1)}2 - \dfrac{n-1}3\\
& = \dfrac{n^3-n}3 - \dfrac{n(n-1)}2 = \dfrac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}6
\end{align}